# GeneXus build for Android fails with "could not find <sdk>\platform-tools\zipalign.exe"

Tags: android, apk, genexus, genexus-sd

After updating to SDK Tools 23 (or newer), whenever I try to build an SD application targeting Android with GeneXus, I get the following message after compilation:

```
error: Could not find: <sdk>\platform-tools\zipalign.exe
Command: zipalign 4 "<path_to_apk-release-unsigned.apk>" "<path_to_apk>"
error: The system cannot find the file specified
Android Compilation Failed
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with SDK Tools 23, `zipalign.exe` was moved again. It is no longer in its previous location (under `<sdk>\tools`), but only in the subdirectories of `<sdk>\build-tools`.

This issue is fixed in GeneXus X Evolution 3 Upgrade 1 (as well as Evolution 2 Upgrade 7). For now, you can avoid this problem by following these steps:

1. Make sure that at least one version of the SDK Build-tools is installed (this is necessary for building anyway).
2. Copy the `zipalign.exe` file from `<sdk>\build-tools\<version>` to `<sdk>\tools` or `<sdk>\platform-tools`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run the SDK Manager and upgrade the Android SDK Tools and Platform Tools. Check Android Build-Tools. Select and Install the package. It is the new package location for zipalign.
2. Update the IDE to point to the new location for zipalign. Start from the main menu in the IDE,

> select Tools >> Options >> Environment Options >> SDK Manager.

Update the ZipAlign location to point to the new Build-Tools directory:

```
    C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\PlatformSDKs\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\zipalign.exe.
```